# rails 3.1 + asset pipeline + webrick returning 406 for requests to /images/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, webrick

i'm using the asset pipeline with rails 3.1 and less.

i have my images stored in app/assets/images.

in my .css.less file i have:

```
background-image: url('image.gif');
```

when the stylesheet gets compiled, it renders the path to the image as follows:

```
background-image: url('/images/image.gif')
```

when these images are requested through webrick, webrick is returning a 406 error code for those requests.  manually requesting `http://localhost/images/image.gif` also returns a 406.

however, a request to `http://localhost/assets/image.gif` works just fine.

when i access the rails server through passenger, using the `/images/image.gif` path works, as does `/assets/image.gif`.

I also tried changing the file to be a .erb file and then using asset_path, with the same results.

I also tried to manually force the `/assets` path by using this in the .css.less file:

```
background-image: url('/assets/image.gif')
```

but that still compiles the css file to use `/images/image.gif`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

background-image: asset-url('image.gif', image);

Comment: I'm not using sass, which I understand should support asset-url. It doesn't seem to work with Less.  Some things online say that asset_url should work as ruby code, but that method isn't recognized in my environment.  I notice that in my sprockets gem source, the function asset_url is defined but both empty and commented out.

Comment: seems like the less-rails gem is missing the asset helper to create the correct path to the images.  https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/1  --  seems like these are added in unreleased version 2.0.2